# Does the Hex spell give disadvantage to saving throws and attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, saving-throw

The Warlock Spell 'Hex' (PHB 251) gives Disadvantage on ability checks.

Does this include saving throws and attacks? That is, in this context, are saving throws and attacks 'ability checks'?

Comment: [Related] [What is the difference between Ability Checks and Saving Throws?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53941/what-is-the-difference-between-ability-checks-and-saving-throws) • [Is an attack a check, or only similar to a check?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14654/is-an-attack-a-check-or-only-similar-to-a-check)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, I almost VTC-ed, but each of those questions only covers 2 of the 3. (Although some of the answers cover all 3.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Disadvantage from the *Hex* spell<sup>1</sup> applies *only* to ability checks.** The [*Player's Basic Rules*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220228192604/https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules) and *Player's Handbook* differentiate ability checks from saving throws and attack rolls from ability checks in Chapter 7: Using Ability Scores. Specifically,

> The three main rolls of the game—the ability check, the saving throw, and the attack roll—rely on the six ability scores. (PBR, p. 57; PHB, p. 173)

Under the subsection Advantage and Disadvantage, it again indicates that these are separate rolls.

> Sometimes a special ability or spell tells you that you have advantage or disadvantage on an ability check, a saving throw, **or** an attack roll. [Emphasis added] (Ibid.)

So while saving throws and attack rolls are based on your ability scores, they are **not** ability checks. In fact, Chapter 7 is dedicated to ability checks and saving throws (not attack rolls).

---

1. The *Hex* spell description states, in relevant part, "choose one ability when you cast the spell. The target has disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability." (PHB, p. 251)

Comment: So, how *Hex* can help during battle? Except extra damage.

Comment: @orkenstein; In battle, Hex can help by making a target more susceptible to shove or disarm or similar (STR (Athletics) or DEX (Acrobatics) ability checks). Cast before battle, it can make a target go later in the order (initiative is a DEX ability check).

Answer (score 8):

According PHB 173, ability check, saving throw and attack are threatened different:

> Sometimes a special ability or spell tells you that you have advantage
>   or disadvantage on an ability check, a saving throw, or an attack
>   roll.

So, the Hex Spell only cause disadvantage in ability checks (PHB 251).

> Also, choose one ability when you cast the spell. The target has
>   disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability.

Comment: Hex can however provide disadvantage on strength checks which will cause 'grapple' or 'shove' special attack options to be made at disadvantage. Useful against giant constrictor snakes among other monsters. Or druids in that form.