# If a Shadow Magic sorcerer casts Darkness using the Eyes of the Dark feature, can they cast another spell that requires concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, concentration

Eyes of the Dark, a feature from the Shadow Magic (Sorcerer) class, allows the PC to cast *darkness* by expending a spell slot, or 2 sorcery points. If I cast the spell in that way (either expending a spell slot or 2 sorcery points) am I allowed to cast another spell that requires Concentration?

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the current wording of your question asks whether a PC can _cast_ another spell that requires concentration, period. I get the sense that what you actually meant to ask is whether you can cast another spell that requires concentration _and still keep up the first spell_. Is that right? Because it's a materially different question.

Answer (score 12):

## No, you can't cast and maintain another concentration spell at the same time

The description of the [Shadow Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic)'s [Eyes of the Dark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#EyesoftheDark-750) feature (XGtE, p. 51) is below:

> When you reach 3rd level in this class, you learn the *darkness* spell, which doesn't count against your number of sorcerer spells known. In addition, you can cast it by spending 2 sorcery points or by expending a spell slot. If you cast it with sorcery points, you can see through the darkness created by the spell.

Nothing in that indicates that the normal rule of [concentrating](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) on only one spell at a time is suspended when you cast the darkness spell by either method. If you cast another concentration spell, your concentration on the darkness spell will end.

Comment: @nitsua60: Note: As of Xanathar's, your second option (cast with effective duration of zero while maintaining *darkness*) is ruled out; [Xanathar's made it clear you lose concentration when you *begin* casting another spell requiring concentration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/149314/28941). [Sage Advice Compendium was also updated, so it's "core"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72186/if-youre-concentrating-on-one-spell-and-you-cast-another-concentration-spell#comment472340_72189).

Comment: @ShadowRanger interesting. It's moot, anyway, since the post covers the "right" analysis, so I'll go ahead and remove my earlier comment.