# Countering a concentration spell while concentrating on darkness

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, spellcasting, concentration

I had a recent rules argument with a couple of fellow players during a spellcasting tournament. I'm a warlock/monk with the concentration spells *silence* and *darkness*, as well as the devil's sight invocation. I was standing in my magical *darkness* completely unseen, and cast *silence* on a space including both other contenders who were unable to move. They didn't have any counterspells left so it wouldn't have affected the outcome, but one of the players wanted to know if they could have counterspelled the silence, considering that I was in *darkness* when I began casting. I don't rightly know, so I'm interested to know if someone could have countered my *silence*.

Comment: Is the crux of your question whether the _darkness_ ends in time to let your opponents see you casting _silence_ so they can counter it?  Or is it "can opponents use _counterspell_ while I'm hidden in darkness?"

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72186/if-youre-concentrating-on-one-spell-and-you-cast-another-concentration-spell related, duplicate? (Answer: concentration ends as soon as you begin casting the second spell, therefore you are visible and counterspell is possible, sorry)

Comment: Tylanderma, I made a number of edits to things I think your question implied, as they are important for generating a correct answer.  Please roll back if any were not correct.  The most important is that the _darkness_ you were in when you cast _silence_ was a magical effect created by your own spell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, they can

> Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

When you *start* casting Silence, that breaks your concentration on Darkness. At that point, they can see and Counterspell you.

Comment: You may want to one of the more explicit quotes: "As soon as you start casting a spell or using a special ability that requires concentration, your concentration on another effect ends instantly." from Xanathar's. Or "If you’re concentrating on a spell, your concentration on it ends immediately when you start casting another spell that requires concentration." from the SAC. The quote you've chosen doesn't actually indicate that "if you cast" = "if you *start* casting"

Comment: @Exempt-Medic I don't want to, but if you do, the edit button is right there.

Comment: And I personally do not believe that is an edit I can make *for* you, **especially** when you've said you don't want that edit. I will point out that my comment has several upvotes, but it's your answer, not mine

Comment: @Exempt-Medic no, it’s the Stacks answer. If you can make it better you don’t need and shouldn’t ask for my permission.