# What spells force the target to make an ability check?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, ability-scores

The warlock spell [Hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex) says:

> choose one ability when you cast the spell. The target has disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability.

I would like to know the spells which impose an ability check in some way either to resist or lessen the effects of the spell.

Related, but separate:
[Choosing the Ability for a Hex](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180600/choosing-the-ability-for-a-hex)

For clarity, I'm only looking for official non-UA material.

Comment: By "forcing an ability check" do you mean spells which explicitly compel an unwilling creature into making one? Do spells which effect can be broken via an ability check also count? For instance, you can discern an illusion via INT check, but the spell itself doesn't "force" you to do so.

Comment: @enkryptor I think force is bad phrasing on my part, your case there is what I'm after. I'll update the question

Comment: Are you looking for spells to take for yourself, or spells for your teammates to synergize with? Because if it's the former, concentration is going to be a limiting factor.

Comment: @ryanc I'm generically looking for synergy with the teammates and/or myself when it's not concentration based

Comment: Are you looking for official/PHB & DMG content only? Does UA count, or homebrew?

Answer (score 5):

This incomplete* list is taken from this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/4cj401/list_of_spells_requiring_target_to_make_ability):

- [Bigby's Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bigbys-hand): Strength (Athletics) check with *Forceful Hand*, or a grapple check (either Athletics or Acrobatics) with *Grasping Hand*
- [Black Tentacles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/black-tentacles): Strength or Dexterity check to escape
- [Bones of the Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bones-of-the-earth): Strength or Dexterity check to escape if successfully restrained.
- [Control Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-water): Strength (Athletics) check in order to swim out of the *Whirlpool*
- [Counter Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell): Casting ability can prevent the spell being countered if the target spell uses a spell slot below level 3
- [Detect Thoughts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-thoughts): Intelligence check to end the spell if it fails an earlier Wisdom Save
- [Disguise Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self): Intelligence (Investigation) check to discern that you are disguised
- [Earthquake](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/earthquake): Strength (Athletics) check to escape if buried in rubble
- [Ensnaring Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ensnaring-strike): Strength check from the target or other creature to escape.
- [Entangle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle): Strength check to escape
- [Freezing Sphere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/freezing-sphere): Strength check to escape if trapped in ice
- [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding): Intelligence (Investigation) check to find the glyph
- [Hallucinatory Terrain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallucinatory-terrain): Intelligence (Investigation) check to disbelieve the illusion
- [Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image): Intelligence (Investigation) check to determine that it is an illusion
- [Maximilian's Earthern Grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maximilians-earthen-grasp): Strength check to escape
- [Maze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maze): Intelligence check to escape (notably, there is no save to avoid the effect in the first place so the check is the only way to avoid the full duration)
- [Minor Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion): Intelligence (Investigation) check to determine that it is an illusion
- [Phantasmal Force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantasmal-force): Intelligence (Investigation) check to end early
- [Programmed Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/programmed-illusion): Intelligence (Investigation) check to determine that it is an illusion
- [Project Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/project-image): Intelligence (Investigation) check to determine that it is an illusion
- [Seeming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/seeming): Intelligence (Investigation) check to recognize the disugise
- [Silent Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silent-image): Intelligence (Investigation) check to determine that it is an illusion
- [Spike Growth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spike-growth): Wisdom (Perception) check to recognize the hazardous terrain
- [Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol): Intelligence (Investigation) check to find the glyph
- [Telekinesis](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/telekinesis): Strength check to avoid being moved and/or restrained
- [Tsunami](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tsunami): Strength (Athletics) check to move out of the wall of water
- [Web](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web): Strength check to escape restraint
- [Whirlwind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/whirlwind): Strength or Dexterity check to escape the whirlwind
- [Wrathful Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wrathful-smite): Wisdom check to end the spell early

---

*: I've not been able to check any spells from after 2016 when that thread was posted.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few class features that also requires ability checks, for example:

Fighter

Arcane Archer

- Grasping Vines: strength(Athletics) check to escape the vines

Rogues

Inquisitive

- Insightful Fighting: Rogue's Wisdom(insight) vs target's Charisma(Deception) for extra sneak attack option

Swashbuckler

- Panache: Rogue's Charisma(persuasion) Vs target's Wisdom(insight) for target on disadvantage on all attacks and unable to make opportunity attacks against creatures other than the Rogue

Comment: While this information seems correct, it does not answer the question, unfortunately, as the question is pretty specific about asking for spells in particular, rather than something more general, such as “game features”.

Comment: While not strictly an answer to the question as asked, I think the implied question of wanting to know which abilities to target for synergy with the Hex spell makes this still a useful answer.

Comment: @linksassin but my spellcaster character, and our other spellcaster party members don't have access to any of these. It's a useful answer, but for a fairly different question.

Comment: I actually find this helpful. The reason I dipped my swashbuckler into warlock in the first place was to get Hex to make panache easier, but found this page to see alternate uses in how I can use Hex to help my party members