# Allowing an attack roll in activity that usualy requires ability check

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

I want to create a homebrew feature that will allow a character to take specific action on advantageous modifiers when lacking in primary means (low ability score or lacking skill/tool proficiency)

I considered using existing features' wording as replacement, but they come with limitations, and narratively such feature should be an attack. Examples of limitations would be *"make an ability check using your spellcasting ability"* from *Counterspell* that doesn't add proficiency modifier or any *"Roll d20"* which couldn't be modified at all.

What changes when I substitute an attack in place of ability check, other than obvious different ability and proficiency modifiers? What mechanics apply to one, but not the other?

Example 1:

Class feature that modifies shove special attack

> #### Eldritch Bash
>
> You can use a bonus action to try to shove a creature within 5 feet of you with your shield, making Melee Spell Attack instead of Strength (Athletics) check against opponent's Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check, not their AC.

Example 2:
Class feature / feat that allows lockpicking with fist rather than doing Dexterity (Thieves' Tools) check.

> #### Percussive Lockpicking
>
> As an action you can make an unarmed attack against lock, treating lockpicking DC as AC. On hit the lock opens.

*(example phrasing subject to change)*

Comment: Please help me with better language to convey that attack is not made against AC but "usual" DC / contest.

Comment: To close- and down-voters: How to make this question more precise? [Is an attack a check, or only similar to a check?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14654) seems similar and points to basics, yet I'm asking for details. I did not include research as it's an answer in itself,.

Comment: I think answering your own question in this situation muddies the waters - what your asking needs clarification, and your own "answer" doesn't seem to actually answer anything.

Comment: @T.J.L.The paragraph before examples are two wordings of the same question and my answer addresses them. Preceeding explanation "what I want" was added in edit, as it was sitting dead at -1.

Answer (score 1):

### Advantage and disadvantage is easier to come with attack than ability checks

Being prone is the simplest example that causes disadvantage on attack but doesn't affect ability checks.

### There are spells that add a bonus to different rolls

[Guidance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guidance) affects only ability checks, [Bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) doesn't, but works on attacks.

### The attack will not be able to do damage

Dealing damage when not intended should not be an issue, as per [Can other damage (from class abilities/feats) be added to net attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86353)

### Magical or damaged weapons will affect the roll

Or [Wand of the War Mage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-the-war-mage) would affect spell attack rolls

### Spell attacks won't work in antimagic field

Spell attacks are considered magical ([How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364)) which Antimagic field suppresses

### No official material can double profficiency in weapons or spells

Unlike Rogue's Expertise

### Cover applies to attacks only